# Visual Studio Code. Regex to search/replace just the apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio

I'm trying to find whatever starts with a word, followed by a `'`, and then followed by a word(`/\w'\w/`). For example(i'm, it's, what's,there's,John's), Take John's for example, it will match `n's`. That is perfect, but once that it is matched I want to replace just the `'` and not `n` and `s`.

Comment: Do you mean replace text in a javascript file you are editing using the VC search and replace?

Comment: It will be best if I do it directly on my txt file using visual studio code regex replace. Or javascript reading through my txt and replacing would also be great. Last hope would be copying my whole txt file into a string, or splitting my txt file using regex with p5.js

Comment: But I said on my title Visual Studio Code. Regex. :O

Comment: It was not clear at all. It could be (and was) interpreted as how to write code in VC that could do that

Comment: I'm sorry man, dw, some moderators fixed it. All good now :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use capturing group.

```
([^'])'([^'])
   |     |________ Group 2
   |
   |______________ Group 1
```

```js
let arr = [`i'm`, `it's`, `what's`,`there's`,`John's`]

arr.forEach(e=>{
  e = e.replace(/([^'])'([^'])/g, "$1$2")
  console.log(e)
})
```

- Press `Ctrl+f` add regex pattern and select `.*` option.
- In add replace value in the second input box `$1$2`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this directly from visual studio code for replacing? instead of copying all my txt into a string?

Comment: @Kadhem yes you can see the images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use capture groups. Let's assume you want to replace the ' with ""

Match RegExp:

```
(\w)'(\w)
```

Replace with "":

```
$1""$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that doesn't use capturing groups, instead using a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```js
const replaced = "John's it's I'm 'not this'".replace(/(?<=\w)'(?=\w)/g, '');

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Does Visual Studio Code support lookbacks? Not sure amma have to try it out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Incredible, it actually works perfectly and highlights exactly what I need. But gonna keep the previous answer, just because he answered first and it still worked, how i wanted it to work.